# String literal to byte

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I am making a forms application is Visual C#. I have a textbox where a user must enter a number and a uppercase letter, example "9D".

What I need to do is put that letter into a byte array as a byte...so in my byte array it would:

```
array[index] = 0x9D
```

I know that the textbox class represents the 9D as a string. I am confused on how to make it into a literal byte (9D) and stick it in the array.

New to .Net so any help would be appreciated. I've looked at the System.Convert class and don't see anything I can use.

Comment: I assume you want to treat 0x9D has 157 correct?

Comment: You can use the [System.Convert.ToByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx) method, specify `16` as your base to convert Hex strings to bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Byte.Parse(string, NumberStyles)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4eszwye3.aspx):

```
byte b = Byte.Parse(text, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Or [`Byte.TryParse(string, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, out Byte)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.tryparse.aspx) to more gracefully handle invalid input.

Comment: Thank you. Byte.Parse(text, NumberStyles.HexNumber) did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @brazc0re - I strongly suggest you use TryParse otherwise your application WILL CRASH if the string is unable to be converted into a base 16 number.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Ramhound. I'll use TryParse instead and handle errors with the try, catch accordingly.

Comment: @brazc0re: The point of `TryParse` is to avoid having to use `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I posted that answer before looking up the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted it done a little faster and to allow '0x' in front of the number you can use `Convert.ToByte("0x9D", 16)`. In my limited testing, [Convert.ToByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx) was twice as fast as `Byte.Parse`

You can also validate the input with a simple [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). This way you know the string will parse before calling any method to parse or convert it.

```
// Checks that the string is either 2 or 4 characters and contains only valid hex
var regex = new Regex(@"^(0x)*[a-fA-F\d]{2}$")
```

Test code:

```
const int count = 100000;
var data = "9D";
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Reset();

byte dest = 0;
sw.Start();
for(int i=0; i < count; ++i)
{
    dest = Byte.Parse(data, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
}
sw.Stop();
var parseTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
for(int i=0; i < count; ++i)
{
    dest = Convert.ToByte(data, 16);
}
sw.Stop();
var convertTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Byte.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k1ats7.aspx) to parse a string into a `Byte`.

```
array[index] = Byte.Parse("9D", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Note that having the prefix `0x` will cause a parse fail, so you may want to strip it out if it exists.